# Handling MySQL errors in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, error-handling

While developing my website I use `mysql_error()` to display errors so I know how to fix them.

My question is... when the website goes live, how should I handle the errors, because I do not want the user to see the errors but instead see a user friendly message like **"Oops, something went wrong"**.

Comment: if mysql error-> your handling script.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, I'd strongly recommend moving from the deprecated `mysql_` functions to either one of the [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) classes. Both are far more secure, and being maintained for current and foreseeable future versions of PHP.

Some possible solutions to displaying an error could be:

```
$sql = new mysqli($host, $user, $password, $database);
$query = //your query

//Option 1
$result = $sql->query($query) or die("Something has gone wrong! ".$sql->errorno);
//If the query fails, kill the script and print out a user friendly error as well 
//as an error number for them to quote to admins if the error continues to occur, 
//helpful for debugging for you, and easier for users to understand

//Option 2
$result = $sql->query($query);
if($result) {
    //if the query ran ok, do stuff
} else {
    echo "Something has gone wrong! ".$sql->errorno;
    //if it didn't, echo the error message
}
```

You could also use the PHP `error_log` function to put a new error into the error log which could contain the full `$sql->error` details for admins to view, and completely skip the `$sql->errorno` printout. For more info on error logging, check the [PHP Docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php)

Answer (score 2):

Normally you want to log these errors in a live enviroment (meaning, you write the error message and some further infromation like time, ip, .. to a file)
On the userside you should also provide the User some feedback, so print a nice error message so that the user knows that something went wrong.

Just use Google to find some Logger-libraries. Mostly, they can be configured to change behaviour in live and development enviroment!
You might also have a look at: https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-3/

Answer (score 0):

While developing your website, you should not use `mysql_error()`, because you should not use any of the `mysql_*` functions, because they are deprecated.

The most basic error handling is to throw an [Exception](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.exception.php). The exception handler should log the error message along with a [stack trace](http://www.php.net/manual/en/exception.gettrace.php) and output an error page.

Answer (score -1):

What you need is to handle the answer you receive from the SQL query. Like if success or if error.
Like this:

```
<?php
    $response = 0;
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");
    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
        $response = "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

    // Perform a query, check for error
    if (!mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO Persons (FirstName) VALUES ('Glenn')")){
        $response = "Error description: " . mysqli_error($con);
    }

    mysqli_close($con);

    echo $response;
?>
```

Then in your Frontend side, you can give a format to your response, with a jQuery plugin, or some framework. I recommend to use: jquery confirm.
References:
https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_error.asp
https://craftpip.github.io/jquery-confirm/

If you want to handle the specific error, try it by detecting the exactly error number code.
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-error-reference.html
https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.errno.php

Answer (score -1):

You can use:
`if (mysqli_error($conn)) {
       $error = 'Oops something went wrong!';
}
echo $error;`

The `$conn`  stands for the database connection through which the query was carried out.